# Test if "name" key of label is empty

Tags: cross-referencing, expansion, nameref, refcount, ltproperties

I'd like to test if the "name" key attached to a label when nameref is loaded is empty. The value can be retrieved expandably with refcount's `\getrefbykeydefault` and tested as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nameref}

\begin{document}

\section{bla} \label{mylab1}
\section{} \label{mylab2}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_if_empty:eTF { \getrefbykeydefault{mylab1}{name}{} }
  { EMPTY }{ NOT~EMPTY }
\par
\tl_if_empty:eTF { \getrefbykeydefault{mylab2}{name}{} }
  { EMPTY }{ NOT~EMPTY }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

[image: expandtest]

However, as soon as the "name" contains nonexpandable tokens, the test errors.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nameref}

\begin{document}

\section{bla\textit{h}} \label{mylab}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_if_empty:eTF { \getrefbykeydefault{mylab}{name}{} }
  { EMPTY }{ NOT~EMPTY }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

produces the error

```
! Argument of \@sect has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.10 ...eTF { \getrefbykeydefault{mylab}{name}{} }
                                                  
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.

Runaway argument?
{\normalfont \Large \bfseries }{\unexpanded {h}}\ifx \reserved@a \@empty \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \@sect was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.10 ...eTF { \getrefbykeydefault{mylab}{name}{} }
                                                  
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
```

I'm aware putting commands like `\textit` in section titles is bad practice. Assuming I don't have control over the input, how can I check whether or not the "name" attached to a label is empty?

---

If I were using ltproperties, I could test the content of the "title" key (note this is comparable to refcount's "name" key, not its "title" key).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nameref}

\begin{document}

\section{bla\textit{h}}
\label{reallabel1}
\RecordProperties{mylab1}{title}

\section{}
\label{reallabel2}
\RecordProperties{mylab2}{title}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_if_empty:eTF { \RefProperty{mylab1}{title} }
  { EMPTY }{ NOT~EMPTY }
\par
\tl_if_empty:eTF { \RefProperty{mylab2}{title} }
  { EMPTY }{ NOT~EMPTY }
\ExplSyntaxOff

%\RefProperty{mylab1}{title} % this errors

\nameref{reallabel1} % but this works

\end{document}
```

[image: ltprop]

Unlike the `\getrefbykeydefault` example, this does not error when the section title contains unexpandable tokens. However this has two issues. First, if you uncomment `\RefProperty{mylab1}{title}`, you get an error, so it is not a replacement for `\nameref`. Second, I'd like this data to be recoverable from just the label data, without needing `\RecordProperties` for every instance.

Comment: This will probably get howls from folks who started using TeX more recently than I did, but here goes.  I'd pack the contents of the `\section` argument into a temporary box that begins with `\ignorespaces`, and then measure the width of that box.  If it's zero, then the box is empty; otherwise it's not.  This shouldn't get hung up by internal uses of font-changes, etc., although an undefined command or real syntax error would be challenged before measurement could take place.

Comment: Why not make the default `\empty` and test for that?  You don't need expl syntax for that, but I supposed you could use it if you really wanted to.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Do you mean test if `\getrefbykeydefault{mylab}{name}{\empty}` is the same as `\empty` with `\ifx`? If so, I think the same issue shows up since you need to expand `\getrefbykeydefault`, assumedly with an `\edef`, and the unexpandable commands break it. Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: the behaviour of \RecordProperties is a bug. I added an issue about that.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Found your use case yet? :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Arbitrary user input should never be put in an `\edef` or expanded with the `e` or `x` type. For a safe expansion, LaTeX provides `\protected@edef` which handles also robust commands.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{nameref}

\begin{document}

\section{bla\textit{h}} \label{mylab}

\ExplSyntaxOn\makeatletter 
\protected@edef\l_tmpa_tl{ \getrefbykeydefault{mylab}{name}{}}
\tl_if_empty:NTF \l_tmpa_tl
  { EMPTY }{ NOT~EMPTY }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```